# the information is not appearing

Tags: c#, database, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have created the database and all the coding. But the Information are now appearing in phone. 
How can I make them  appearing?
it could not show me any details. it shows me that it cannot go to  this line from coding  "this.listBox.ItemsSource = CarScores;"

```
//Main Page Coding .xaml.CS
 namespace carDatabaseCreater
{
 public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
 {

    public static List<Car> CarScoresList = new List<Car>();
    Uri uri;
    Grid CarGrid;
    CarHisrotyRepository CarHisrotyRepository;
    ObservableCollection<Car> CarScores;


    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        this.DisplayCarHistory();
        this.UpdateCarScoresFromDB();
    }


      public void SaveCarToCarHistory(Car _Car)
      {
           CarHisrotyRepository _CarHisrotyRepository = new CarHisrotyRepository();

         Car item0 = new Car() { CarName = "Arion", CarSupplierName = "Bahowan", CarImage = "Image/BMW.jpg", CarCompanyName = "Toyota" };
         Car item1 = new Car() { CarName = "Arion", CarSupplierName = "Bahowan", CarImage = "Image/BMW.jpg", CarCompanyName = "Toyota" };
         Car item2 = new Car() { CarName = "Arion", CarSupplierName = "Bahowan", CarImage = "Image/BMW.jpg", CarCompanyName = "Toyota" };
         Car item3 = new Car() { CarName = "Arion", CarSupplierName = "Bahowan", CarImage = "Image/BMW.jpg", CarCompanyName = "Toyota" };
         Car item4 = new Car() { CarName = "Arion", CarSupplierName = "Bahowan", CarImage = "Image/BMW.jpg", CarCompanyName = "Toyota" };
         CarScoresList.Add(item0);
         _CarHisrotyRepository.Save(item0);
        CarScoresList.Add(item1);
         _CarHisrotyRepository.Save(item1);
         CarScoresList.Add(item2);
         _CarHisrotyRepository.Save(item2);
         CarScoresList.Add(item3);
         _CarHisrotyRepository.Save(item3);
         CarScoresList.Add(item4);
         _CarHisrotyRepository.Save(item4);


     }

     private void UpdateCarScoresFromDB()
     {
         CarHisrotyRepository CarHisrotyRepository = new carDatabaseCreater.CarHisrotyRepository();

         List<Car> AllGames = CarHisrotyRepository.allQuery(CarHisrotyRepository.CarContext).ToList();


         }


     public void DisplayCarHistory()
     {
         this.CarHisrotyRepository = new CarHisrotyRepository();

         // Get Game History from IsoStore
         List<Car> CarHistory = this.CarHisrotyRepository.Load();

         // Display to Screen
        CarScores = new ObservableCollection<Car>(CarHistory);
        this.listBox.ItemsSource = CarScores;// the Error appears here
      }

    }
   }
```

Comment: You've given *far* too much code here. Please cut it down to just a short but complete program which *only* contains relevant code - a cut down version of your real app, in other words, which still demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I could not post  a snap photo from the error

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that. Your question still contains large swathes of whitespace, commented out methods, lots of items when presumably just two would be enough, and "the Error appears here" without even a description of what the error is.

Comment: my program can not go through it and appearing my result it just. can not recognize it

Comment: "Cannot go through it" isn't a technical description of the error. It's the equivalent of telling your doctor that you're not very well. Sorry, but without more description no-one's going to be able to help you.

Comment: what  I mean that the program cannot read this line from code

Comment: And that's the most detailed description you can give? There's no error message? No exception? The world just stops? Is the problem when you compile, or when you run? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints You still haven't edited the code to remove extraneous bits such as the commented-out method, by the way.

Comment: I removed them. The problem appears when i run the code

Comment: Thanks @AlaaMasoud  That gives me an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see any line of code where you put the cars grid to the visual tree. Maybe this is the reason?

Comment: (n) ////////////////////////////////